# I recently had an error running a code in netbeans due to empty line

Tags: java, netbeans

the code worked after I removed an empty line and when I added the empty line it showed an error again. is this possible?this happened when I used the executeUpdate() method and left a line between the it and the previous setString().

```
public boolean addDriver(String name, String gender, String ad, String phn,
                         String exp, String dob, String doj, String path, String carnum) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement psmt;
        String str = "insert into driverdetails(name, gender, address, phoneno, experience, dob, dateofjoin, path, carnumber) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        psmt = con.prepareStatement(str);
        psmt.setString(1,name);
        psmt.setString(2,gender);
        psmt.setString(3,ad);
        psmt.setString(4,phn);
        psmt.setString(5,exp);
        psmt.setString(6,dob);
        psmt.setString(7,doj);
        psmt.setString(8,path);
        psmt.setString(9,carnum);
        int res = psmt.executeUpdate();

        return res > 0;

    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in connection");
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Unlike Python, whitespace doesn't have any particular meaning to Java. It could be that the line you deleted included a non-printing character, but if you bothered to include the error message, it would be easier to determine the cause.

Comment: I am sorry but I meant that the compiler would enter the catch block if there was an empty line between the psmt.setString(9,carnum); and int res = psmt.executeUpdate(); methods. it did not show any other error in the output.

Comment: Well... you stomped on the exception by catching it and just putting up a dialog. Add the line `e.printStackTrace()` to your catch block to see the exception.

Comment: I did that and the error i got was: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'path' at row 1

Comment: well this is embarrassing..it was pure coincidence that when I left a line I chose an image with a long name n when I dint I chose one with a short name...what a waste of question

Comment: At least you know what happened. And who knows? Someone else could run into the same thing.